# Finding domain and range of $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

Given that $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$. Find the domain and range.

The book gives the hint of $\forall x\in \mathbb{R}$. But I don't understand. Can anyone explain to me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint:  graphing the function helps a lot.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** What is the maximum value that $f(x)$ attains? That is, how can we make the denominator as small as possible? Does the graph $y = f(x)$ have any asymptotes? Is $f(x)$ ever negative?

Answer (score 0):

$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

The textbook makes it an easier problem by letting us know that *f*(*x*) is a real-valued function.

A good approach for domain and range problems is using a number line.

If *x* is a very small negative number, its square is a very large positive number. Add one to a very large positive number is an even bigger positive number. We can carry this logic out to the positive numbers as well as the numbers near zero.

We find that the denominator has no discontinuities; there is no real number for which it is undefined. (The graph, as others have suggested, make this easier to see). Even at small numbers in the interval about zero, the function still has a real output value.

So, the domain is infinite, like your book says, it includes every real number.

The range is a bit trickier. We are trying to maximize the expression $\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$.

For a moment, just consider $\frac{1}{x}$. This expression grows infinitely large as *x* approaches zero. We want to find, then, the smallest value that $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ takes. We are trying to minimize that quantity. 1 is a constant we can do nothing about so forget about it temporarily. Now look at $x^2$. It is always positive. And this is a familiar shape, the classic parabola. It has a minimum when x=0, because if $x≠0$, then its value is positive, i.e., >0.

So, if we let *x*=0, then we see that $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ takes on the value 1, and the overall function value ($\frac{1}{1} $) is 1. This is our maximum function value.

To find the minimum, just ask ourselves a simple question (about the limit as x approaches either +∞ or -∞). If x grows really really big, then $x^2$ grows really really big. The add one just makes it slightly bigger. As $x^2 +1$ grows bigger and bigger, $\sqrt{x^2+1}$ grows bigger and bigger. This means that the inverse of $\sqrt{x^2+1}$, the function, grows smaller and smaller (as the denominator grows larger and larger the overall fraction value decreases).

But, does it every reach zero? No. In order for *f*(*x*) to equal zero, then the numerator of the function, 1 would have to be zero, but 1≠0. No, in the limit we tend towards zero. And obviously, a ratio of two positive numbers, 1 and the square root of a positive number, *x*^2+1, is always positive; we can never have zero or a negative number.

However, at infinity, the range does approach zero. We can indicate this with soft parentheses, in interval notation.

Finally, we get that if: 
$f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x^2+1}}$

then:

*x*∈$ℝ$

*f*(*x*)∈ (0,1]

[image: ...in all its bell-curve-like glory.]